# Ninject register by convention with names

Tags: ninject, ninject-extensions

Is there a way to register with Ninject, using conventions, all classes that implement a certain interface, associated with each class' name?

```
interface IClientCodeValidator
{
    string ValidateClientCode(params IXpressionNode[] customParameters);
    string ValidatorName { get; }
}

public class Client1CodeValidator: IClientCodeValidator
{
    public Client1CodeValidator()
    {
         this.ValidatorName = "Client1";
    }
}

public class Client2CodeValidator: IClientCodeValidator
{
    public Client2CodeValidator()
    {
         this.ValidatorName = "Client2";
    }
}

Bind<IClientCodeValidator>()
        .To.ItsClasses()
        .InSingletonScope()
    .Named(*c => c.ValidatorName*); <--
```

Then later

```
Container.Instance.Get<IClientCodeValidator>(clientName.ToUpper())
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're going about this is an anti-pattern called Service Locator. The recommended approach would be to use Abstract Factory instead. In that pattern, you would have an additional interface that is responsible for resolving the correct concrete implementation. For your example:

```
interface IClientCodeValidatorFactory
{
    IClientCodeValidator GetFor(string client);
}

public class ClientCodeValidatorFactory : IClientCodeValidatorFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public ClientCodeValidatorFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public IClientCodeValidator GetFor(string client)
    {
        // load from your configuration how client names are associated to Validators
        return _kernel.Get<IClientCodeValidator>(validatorName)
    }
}
```

this way you can inject `IClientCodeValidatorFactory` into your constructor and avoid using `Container.Instance` altogether.

then you can use [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions) to automatically bind validators to the interface:

```
kernel.Bind( x => x
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<IClientCodeValidator>()
    .BindAllInterfaces()
    .Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope()));
```

Comment: Ok, how do I hook up the factory in the second snippet? I tried using 
`.Configure( c =>     c.InSingletonScope().NamedLikeFactoryMethod((IClientCodeValidatorFactory f) => f.GetFor()`
 but then I have to provide a parameter to the GetFor() method.

Comment: you would hook up the factory as a simple binding: `Bind<IClientCodeValidatorFactory>().To<ClientCodeValidatorFactory>();`, inject it into the consuming class's constructor, and then call `GetFor` in user code.